# Copy Cell Value To Defined Sheet & Cell Reference (Loop)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy

I'm trying to copy values from a range based on a user defined sheet and cell reference. For example in A1 I have defined the Sheet Name to be copied to, B1 is the cell reference to be copied to & C1 is the value to be copied. The below code completes this for row 1 only, but I require to loop this for all rows in a defined range (i.e. named range A1:C200) or until the row is blank.

Preferably I would have an option to copy the cell value in the range (e.g. C1 as above) or the formula that exists in the range.

```
Sub CopyValues()

Dim SheetName
Dim CellRef
Dim Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
SheetName = Range("A1").Value
CellRef = Range("B1").Value
Value = Range("C1").Value
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Range(CellRef).Value = Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there

```
Sub CopyValues()

Dim SheetName
Dim CellRef
Dim Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 to 200
        SheetName = Range("A" & i).Value
        CellRef = Range("B" & i).Value
        Value = Range("C" & i).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Range(CellRef).Value = Value
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyValues()
    With ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell in .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range(cell.Offset(,1).Formula = cell.Offset(,2).Formula
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both!
I settled on the below which solved my problem.

```
Sub CopyValues()

Dim SheetName
Dim CellRef
Dim Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = Range("SheetNameRange").Row To Range("SheetNameRange").Row + Range("SheetNameRange").Rows.Count - 1
        SheetName = Range("A" & i).Value
        CellRef = Range("B" & i).Value
        Value = Range("C" & i).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Range(CellRef).Value = Value
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```